# Correctly return pointer to key/value pair from bespoke associative container & iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, containers, return-type

I have an associative container that is implemented internally as two linear arrays, one of keys, and one of values. Both arrays are kept sorted so a binary search of keys yields the index of the value. This is done to improve the performance of searches when the size relationship between keys and values is grossly asymmetric. The container use case is modified rarely but searched often, which is why we have designed it this way.

```
template<typename Key, typename Value>
struct Container
{
  // allocated on create
  Key* mKeys;
  Value* mValues; 
  unsigned mCount;

  class iterator
  {
       Container* mContainer;
       unsigned mIndex;

       // return a pair that can support mutating the value but not the key
       std::pair<const Key &,Value &> MakePair() { 
           return std::make_pair( mContainer->mKeys[mIndex], 
                                  mContainer->mValues[mIndex] ); 
           };
  
       // I don't have a std::pair to return here; and I can't return a temporary.
       std::pair<const Key,Value> & operator*();   
       std::pair<const Key,Value> * operator->();  
  }

}
```

I am trying to implement an `iterator` over the container that returns a key/value pair similar to `std::map`.

My concern is around `reference operator*()` and `pointer operator->()`, where I don't actually have a `std::pair` to return a reference to. However, I would still like to use the syntax of `container.begin()->first`, or `(*container.begin()).second`.

Does anyone have any insights on how I can return a reference or pointer to a `std::pair<const key, value>` here? Or, can I simply return something by value which holds references to the key and value, named `first` and `second`, respectively, to get compliance?

Comment: have a static 'empty' pair that you return

Comment: @pm100 I had thought about this but in multithreaded environments this could cause issues,

Comment: why, its an empty value I assume the callers wont write to it

Comment: @Steven you can use thread-local storage to solve that